# How to access attributes from vuetify elements programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have some v-text-fields from Vuetify, which have a specific background-color. Looks like this (tried to remove irrelevant information):

```
<v-text-field id="someId" ref="someRef" background-color="someColor"
:label="attributeName"
v-model=someValue
outline
clearable
></v-text-field>
```

I want to access the background-color property via js, to change it when some event occurs.
But I can't figure out how to access this value.
I can change it manually by using :background-color=outlineColor
e.g.

```
data() {
return {
outlineColor: "blue"
}
 },
```

and then assign outlineColor = "someOtherColor" in javascript.

But as I have multiple text fields (created via v-for) and I want to change the colors for all text fields individually, I need to access the specific text field and its background-color manually, instead of changing it for all text fields at once.

I tried it with

```
this.$refs.someRef
```

but can't find the background-color there.

I also tried finding it at

```
document.getElementById("someId").style
```

but the only thing I can find there is backgroundColor (which is not background-color), it changes the background color of the text instead of the outline color (the color of the frame around the input field).
Hope you can imagine it.

Thanks for any hints in advance,
kalsari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use manual DOM queries when you don't need to. This is one of the cases where you really don't need to.

You change the background color in the same way you assign different models to each of your text fields. You either create a computed property that allows you to easily select a field from the object you get in your `v-for`, or you use the `v-for` index to look up a value.

E.g.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="textBoxIndex in 5">
      <v-text-field
        :background-color="this.colors[textBoxIndex]"
        :label="this.labels[textBoxIndex]"
        v-model=this.models[textBoxIndex]
        outline
        clearable
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

If you loop through actual objects, e.g. with `v-for="myTextbox in myTextboxes"`, you can get the index with `v-for="(myTextbox, index) in myTextboxes"`. You can use a computed property to modify the `myTextbox` objects you get from looping through `myTextboxes`, but it will get a little bit weird with the models. Either use manual `@input` events to modify the right value, use the index to select the right model rather than the computed property, or figure out something different entirely.

Comment: it's now working, thanks. but just because I'm curious, even if it would be a bad practice here - what would be the correct way to access it via DOM?

Comment: `this.$refs.someRef` should afaik be an array if you use a v-for on that element. Each element in that array should be the top-most dom element that is defined in `v-text-field` (probably a div of some kind). Using it would be hard, because every time you rerender the template (probably because some data changed), you potentially break the background-color. You end up with some nasty watchers updating the DOM manually through those refs.